# Dummy Output Ubuntu 22.10 + Intel Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS + i5 10210U

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, intel, services

Well guys, im new into Ubuntu, and i have this problem,i'm totally sure that my sound card is not broken, because at the beggining when i was with 22.04 LTS, it worked, until i paired a bluetooth device to my laptop, after that, audio only works with bluetooth, otherway it doesnt, i think that i already tried basically all type of things avaible, (because of that im using 22.10 now lmao). Just i dont know what i can do, im almost going to surrender, so posting here is my last chance. Feel free to ask me to run any command if you need the info. Currently using Ubuntu 22.10, Kinetic. I already tried re-installing pulseaudio, killing the service, work with Alsa, also installed sof-firmware, but nothing worked... or maybe i did something wrong. Please help me and thank you in advance for your time :)

inxi -A command in terminal give me the following info:

```
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-31-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.58 running: yes
```

Update, i think that i almost got it, reading around the web, i think that im having this issue: "https://www.linux.org/threads/dummy-output-ubu-22-10-please-help-im-devastated.41066/"

my output for inxi -xxz --audio is the following:

```
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
    bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:02c8
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-31-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 16.1 running: no
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.58 running: yes
```

So i run

```
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio
```

it works, but then i run

```
systemctl --user start pulseaudio
```

and i get

```
Job for pulseaudio.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl --user status pulseaudio.service" and "journalctl --user -xeu pulseaudio.service" for details.
```

here are the detais for each file:

```
systemctl --user status pulseaudio.service
× pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-02-10 13:13:55 -03; 8s ago
TriggeredBy: × pulseaudio.socket
    Process: 15791 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 15791 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 47ms

feb 10 13:13:55 ulises-M-140BI5 systemd[1688]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
feb 10 13:13:55 ulises-M-140BI5 systemd[1688]: Stopped Sound Service.
feb 10 13:13:55 ulises-M-140BI5 systemd[1688]: pulseaudio.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
feb 10 13:13:55 ulises-M-140BI5 systemd[1688]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
feb 10 13:13:55 ulises-M-140BI5 systemd[1688]: Failed to start Sound Service.
```

and

```
journalctl --user -xeu pulseaudio.service
░░ 
░░ Automatic restarting of the unit UNIT has been scheduled, as the result for
░░ the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
feb 10 13:13:55 ulises-M-140BI5 systemd[1688]: Stopped Sound Service.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit UNIT has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A stop job for unit UNIT has finished.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 1935 and the job result is done.
feb 10 13:13:55 ulises-M-140BI5 systemd[1688]: pulseaudio.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
feb 10 13:13:55 ulises-M-140BI5 systemd[1688]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit UNIT has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
feb 10 13:13:55 ulises-M-140BI5 systemd[1688]: Failed to start Sound Service.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit UNIT has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 1935 and the job result is failed.
```

i keep looking for the solution for making run

```
systemctl --user start pulseaudio
```

but nothing worked yet, any help would be nice, thanks in advance, again.

Comment: Are you using pipewire or pulseaudio? `inxi -A`will tell you. Add it to your question, not into the comments.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?
I got an error close to yours, with the same sound card

Comment: I solved the issue, or something like that. the main problem was that the drivers where from some weird japan company, it was not about linux the problem, i went to windows and i got the same problem, i used some weird drivers downloader from shady websites, and someway it fixed my problem, i had to use the translator from japanese to realize what was happening, but it fixed it. Sadly rn im using windows because i didnt find a way to fix it for Ubuntu.